# Is there a method to plot vectors on a time series with Plotly?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

### Initial question

I'm working on moving some code away from Matlab, and I need to replicate this plot:
[Vector time series of wind observations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiMTO.png)

My attempts thus far have used [`plotly.figure_factory.create_quiver()`](https://plotly.com/python/quiver-plots/), which timed out after about 5 or 6 minutes, and adding a series of [`plotly.add_shape(typ="line")`](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/) to a `plotly.graph_objects.Figure()` but that also was taking over 3 minutes before I interrupted it.

I wonder if it is even possible to convert this kind of plot into a javascript engine like Plotly or if I should be looking at a different type of plot to replace it. Thanks!

### Edit 1

I have run some tests on samples of the data set, and I'm seeing a 4x increase in time for every doubling of the sample size. So to @Joran Beasley's comment, it does seem like too much data for the JS plotting engine.

Comment: its probably just too many data points(ie it would likely be super slow even if it was a scatter plot or simple line graph) ... the best js charting engine i have encountered for dealing with a large number of data points is canvasjs ... another possibility would be to aggregate the points to a smaller subset ... just make sure to aggregate wind direction correctly

Comment: It is a lot of data, `df['data'].size = 67230` for this dataset.